# Convert numbers to strings when reading an excel spreadsheet into a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I'm reading some excel spreadsheets (xlsx format) into pandas using `read_excel`, which generally works great. The problem I have is that when a column contains numbers, pandas converts these to float64 type, and I would like them to be treated as strings. After reading them in, I can convert the column to str:

```
my_frame.my_col = my_frame.my_col.astype('str')
```

This works as far as assigning the right type to the column, but when I view the values in this column, the strings are formatted in scientific-format e.g. 8.027770e+14, which is not what I want. I'd like to work out how to tell pandas to read columns as strings, or do the conversion later so that I get values in their original (non-scientific) format.

Comment: `read_excel` uses an external module, the dtypes will be embedded in your excel sheet so there is no `dtype` param as such you'd have to export as csv and use `read_csv` with `dtype` param or convert as a post-processing step

Answer (score 0):

[pandas.read_**csv**()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_csv.html) has a `dtype` argument:

> dtype : Type name or dict of column -> type
>
> ```
> Data type for data or columns. E.g. {‘a’: np.float64, ‘b’: np.int32}
> ```

Comment: Thanks. I could convert the excel files to csv format first using xlrd, although ideally I'd like to avoid this additional step.

Answer (score 0):

I solve it with round, if you do round(number,5) in most case you will not lose data and you will get zero in the case of 8.027770e+14